# Faster way to filter pandas dataframe and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given df

```
   ticker  close   open
0    AAPL    1.2    1.1
1    TSLA   25.0   27.0
2    TSLA   83.0   80.0
3    TSLA   95.0   93.0
4    CCL   234.0  234.2
5    AAPL  512.0  520.0
```

My purpose:

(1) Apply functions to each ticker dataframe (subset)

(2) Create new column with values in string like 'exist' to each ticker dataframe

My expected output

```
   ticker  close   open  candlestick   SMA_20     SMA_50
0    AAPL    1.2    1.1  bullish      (number)   (number)
1    TSLA   25.0   27.0  bearish      (number)   (number)
2    TSLA   83.0   80.0  bullish      (number)   (number)
3    TSLA   95.0   93.0  bullish      (number)   (number)
4    CCL   234.0  234.2  bearish      (number)   (number)
5    AAPL  512.0  520.0  bearish      (number)   (number)
```

I've tried this code, which is extremely slow

```
for x in df.ticker:
    df_ticker = df[df.ticker == x]
    df_close_price = pd.DataFrame(df_ticker.close)
    for days in [20,50]:
       df_ticker[f'SMA_{days}'] = df_close_price.apply(lambda c: abstract.SMA(c, days))
    ......
    df_result = df_result.append(df_ticker)
```

I was wondering how to filter the dataframe by ticker in a faster way when dealing with millions rows. Many suggested using `.loc`, `numpy`, but I could not find a possible way to perform.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: Also what is your solution which is slow?

Comment: @jezrael I've just edited!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['candlestick'] = np.where(df['close'] > df['open'], 'bullish', 'bearish')
print (df)
  ticker  close   open candlestick
0   AAPL    1.2    1.1     bullish
1   TSLA   25.0   27.0     bearish
2   TSLA   83.0   80.0     bullish
3   TSLA   95.0   93.0     bullish
4    CCL  234.0  234.2     bearish
5   AAPL  512.0  520.0     bearish
```

EDIT: Here is possible use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with custom functionand mainly pass Series to `abstract.SMA` instead `.apply(lambda c: abstract.SMA(c, days)`:

```
def f(x):
    for days in [20,50]:
        x[f'SMA_{days}'] = abstract.SMA(x.close, days)
    return x  
    
df = df.groupby('ticker')['close'].apply(f)
print (df)
```

Comment: How about any faster way to replace `df.apply` to perform function like talib?

Comment: @PythonAnalyst - It should be slowier, because more complicated

Comment: I have to filter the whole dataframe by ticker to perform talib functions indeed